# Showing data after hard refresh

Tags: laravel, vue.js

im working with vue & laravel.i have a edit profile page with some forms in it(name,email,...)
the default value of this form not showing for the first time, but if user refresh the page everything will be work!!!

```
<template>
 <label>Name:</label>
 <input type="text" v-model="name">
 <label>Email:</label>
 <input type="email" v-model="email">
<template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            name:'',
            email:'',
        }
    },
    mounted : function(){
        this.getVueItems();
    },
     methods: {
        getVueItems: function(){
            axios.get('./api/auth/me').then(response => {
                var vm = this;
                vm.name = response.data.name;
                vm.email = response.data.email;
            });
        },

        getAuthUser () {
            this.user = this.$store.getters.currentUser
        },

        updateAuthUser () {
            this.submiting = true,
            axios.put('./api/auth/update', {
                name:this.name,
                email:this.email,
            })
            .then(response => {
                // this.submiting = false;
                location.reload(true);
                // success();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.submiting = false;
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

whats is the problem?

Comment: Your code between <template> tags also will not work like that. You need parent `<div>` to have valid code here

Comment: Yes this is a SFC. You need a root tag between your <template></template>

Comment: this is sample in real code im put beetween <main></main> tag

Answer (score 0):

As you are using arrow function this keyword is already accessible inside the function.
 And for this you should first check in console if you are getting proper response value from api in console.
 Hence change your function as below and check once.

```
 async getVueItems() {
  await axios.get('./api/auth/me').then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.name = response.data.name;
      this.email = response.data.email;
  });
```

Comment: config:
adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
data: undefined

so this is a problem from backend but why the first return nothing and then after refresh send it correctly

Comment: sorry i'm not understrand

Comment: Replace your function with the one i have added and check.